# Issue with SQL in php not working as expected

Tags: php, sql

Hi i have two sql statements the first one is

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 2 
    ReaderData.ReaderIndex, 
    ReaderData.CardID,
    ReaderData.ReaderDate, 
    ReaderData.ReaderTime, 
    ReaderData.controllerID, 
    Left([dtReading],10) AS [date], 
    ReaderData.dtReading 
    FROM ReaderData 
    WHERE ReaderData.controllerID=$this->Id 
    ORDER BY ReaderData.ReaderIndex desc;";
```

and the second one which is

```
$sql = "SELECT 
    [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[MACHINE], 
    [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[cycletime]
    WHERE [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[MACHINE]=$this->name
    FROM [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN]";
```

the first one works as expected however the second one does not work with the WHERE in there if i remove it then it spits out one of the enterys in the table and i am not sure why Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since I am assuming `[SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[MACHINE]` is a string, try putting quotes around the dynamic `$this->name` part of the query. e.g.

   WHERE [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[MACHINE]='$this->name'
2. Also, the `WHERE` clause must appear **after** the `FROM` clause:

   SELECT [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[MACHINE], [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[cycletime]
   FROM [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN]
   WHERE [SHOP FLOOR PRODUCTION PLAN].[MACHINE]='$this->name'

Comment: Hi, That didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: The second point did it i assume not having the FROM before the WHERE was screwing it up Thank you

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If this answers your question, be sure to accept so others know that it fixed the problem.